# I have a style set programmatically that I wish to ignore when printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, styles

The code's simple enough:

page.aspx

```
<body id ="PageBody" runat ="server">
```

page.aspx.cs

```
if ($foo == "foo")
{
    PageBody.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
}
```

I'd like to ignore the background color entirely when the page is printed (the PCs printing will have background turned on in their print settings for various reasons and it cannot be disabled)

I haven't worked too much with CSS from within C#, so maybe there's a way to set the body to use a specific CSS object ID conditionally? If that's the case, I can just set the BG color in the style.css and leave it out in the print.css.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Took a bit more searching but adding the attribute "class" seems to do the trick.

I just call my green background when the criteria is met and call the standard style when not. Both have no background color in the print style sheet.

Comment: Look up "CSS Media types"  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html is a good starting reference.

Comment: I'm familiar with setting media types in style sheets. What I'm looking to do is basically override my code in the case that the page gets printed.

Using

    style.add("background-color", "green");

overrides the style sheets entirely.

Comment: If you are familiar with css media types then I'm not sure what the question is. Simply set your green background style sheet on the normal display css, and clear it on the print style sheet.

Comment: The style sheets are overridden based on the code I posted originally.

When the condition is met to change the background color to green, it ignores the style sheets completely, both screen and print.

Comment: So then don't override the style in code, add a class to the element that applies a style.  Then override that style in the print css style sheet.

Comment: Then have the code alter css classes instead of directly writing to the style attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the background color on the `body` element as a style attribute inline (the way you're doing) overrides the print stylesheet due to specificity. ([Further worthwhile reading on CSS specificity is here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).)

To get around this, you can either:

1. Not set the background color as an inline style (perhaps by adding a CSS class to the `body` element instead and styling that from CSS), or
2. Add `!important` after the background style defined in the print stylesheet, i.e. in print.css do:

   ```
   body {
       background-color: transparent !important;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is what I was going for, but in searching for the attribute to add I hadn't thought it was as simple as Attributes.Add("class"...